# How to use Product Chooser Widget with UI Component Form

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, adminform, widget, product-chooser

I want to have a field in my UI Component form and a "Select Product..." Button where I can choose a product and it gets inserted into the input.
Similar to the "Catalog Product Link" Widget.

[image: Catalog Product Link Widget]

Started by adding this to my ui_component form.xml but without desired result:

```
<fieldset name="assign_products" sortOrder="40">
    <settings>
        <collapsible>true</collapsible>
        <label translate="true">Products</label>
    </settings>
    <container name="assign_products_container" sortOrder="160">
        <htmlContent name="html_content">
            <block name="my_assigned_products" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Widget\Chooser">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="button" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="open" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Select Product...</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </htmlContent>
    </container>
</fieldset>
```

Any tips?

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution to this? Currently working on something similar at the moment.

Comment: @DavidWilkinson unfortunately not ...

Comment: Check out my solution here, I got it working in the end: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/277268/product-chooser-field-for-ui-component-form/278119#278119

Answer (score 2):

You can"t use widget block in uiform. It will not work, because it rendering differently as in widget form. But you can use this functionality creating form extending *Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic*
But it is **deprecated**

Example

```
class Form extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic
{  


    protected $_entityRepository;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        FormFactory $formFactory,      
        EntityRepositoryInterface $_entityRepository,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_entityRepository= $_entityRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $entityId = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('entity_id');
        if($entityId ){
            $entity = $this->_entityRepository->getById($entityId );
        }
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            ['data' => ['id' => 'edit_form', 'action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post']]
        );

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('entity_details', ['legend' => __('EntityDetails')]);

        if ($entityId ) {
            $fieldset->addField('id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'id']);
        }

        $productChooser = $fieldset->addField(
            'product_id',
            'label',
            [
                'label' => __('Product'),
                'required' => true,
                'class' => 'widget-option',
                'visible' => '1',
                'name' => 'product_id',
                'value' => $entityId ?'product/'.$entity ->getProductId():''
            ]
        );
        $chooser = $this->_layout->createBlock('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Widget\Chooser');
        $configChooser = [
            'button' => [
                'open' => __('Select Products'),
                'type' => '\Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Widget\Chooser',
            ]
        ];
        $chooser->setConfig($configChooser)
            ->setFieldsetId('entity_details')
            ->prepareElementHtml($productChooser);

        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this Magento 2 module. https://github.com/graschik/magento-2-admin-ui/blob/master/docs/ui-components/entities-selector/README.md

Example:

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    ...
    <fieldset>
        ...
        <component name="products" class="Grasch\AdminUi\Component\EntitiesSelector" component="Grasch_AdminUi/js/view/components/entities-selector">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Products</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">product_listing</item>
                    <item name="columnsName" xsi:type="string">product_columns</item>
                    <item name="selectionsColumnName" xsi:type="string">ids</item>
                    <item name="grid" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="id" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="original_name" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                                <item name="type" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">ID</item>
                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                                <item name="fit" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="sku" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="original_name" xsi:type="string">sku</item>
                                <item name="type" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">SKU</item>
                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">15</item>
                                <item name="fit" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="name" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="original_name" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                                <item name="type" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Name</item>
                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                                <item name="fit" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="thumbnail" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="original_name" xsi:type="string">thumbnail_src</item>
                                <item name="type" xsi:type="string">thumbnail</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Thumbnail</item>
                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">16</item>
                                <item name="fit" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </component>
        ...
    </fieldset>
    ...
</form>
```